# Bounce animation on button progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an form that has a number of inputs. When I start completing the fields from my form, the background color of my button will start working as a progress. If i have 4 inputs, each input will complete 25% of the button color width.

I've done doing this but I am struggling adding a bounce effect on the last step before full bar. I want to make a bounce animation effect that will go something like this.

```
====  |
======|
====  |
======|
```

This effect will look like the progress hit the right border of my button, will jump a little to left and then will load back as 100%.

Can someone help me with the animation? Thanks a lot!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Progress Bar Example</title>
  <style>
    form {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    label {
      margin: 10px;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
      margin-top: 30px;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <label>
    Input 1:
    <input type="text" id="input1">
  </label>
  <label>
    Input 2:
    <input type="text" id="input2">
  </label>
  <label>
    Input 3:
    <input type="text" id="input3">
  </label>
  <label>
    Input 4:
    <input type="text" id="input4">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  const input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  const input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  const input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
  const input4 = document.getElementById("input4");
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

  [input1, input2, input3, input4].forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
      const completedInputs = [input1, input2, input3, input4].filter(
              (input) => input.value !== ""
      );
      const percentageComplete = completedInputs.length / 4;
      const colorWidth = Math.floor(percentageComplete * submitBtn.clientWidth);
      submitBtn.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, #20ff0c ${colorWidth}px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ${colorWidth}px)`;
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this with a gradient background. Use a pseudo element on the button and animate its width using a cubic bezier. Here's a quick example.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.7s cubic-bezier(.27, 1.99, .13, .24);
  background: #000;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.box:before {
  width: 0;
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.box:before {
  width: 33%;
}

input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.box:before {
  width: 66%;
}

input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.box:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="width" checked>
<label>0</label>

<input type="radio" name="width">
<label>1</label>

<input type="radio" name="width">
<label>2</label>

<input type="radio" name="width">
<label>3</label>


<div class="box"></div>
```